# Is it possible to show the subtitle in an AVI movie?

Tags: subtitles, avi

Is it possible to show the subtitle in an AVI movie ?

Note: I don't want to add the subtitle to the movie, I just want to show them from a downloaded file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as the player supports it.  VLC does, and so do many others.

The convention is to name the subtitle file the same as the video file, but with a different file extension (like .srt), and the player will automatically pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate file containing the subtitle information with the same file name as the AVI file, except having a .sub extension.  Put the file in the same folder as the AVI file.

For Windows Media Player, do the following:

Install DirectVobSub  [Click here to download](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/DirectVobSub.htm)

Play the movie with Windows Media Player

While the movie is playing, Click on Play -> Captions and Subtitles -> On if available

Here's a list of places to download subtitles for popular videos [Link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-subtitle-sources-movies-tv-series/)

Please note that different versions of Windows Media Player may have menus arranged in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The determining factor is your AVI player.

VLC media player (available for Windows, Linux, and Mac) has a dropdown menu that allows you to load the file from a specific location.

See this site for more information: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-add-subtitles-to-a-movie-or-television-series/

Comment: Vlc is the final answer

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can Add Subtitles In any AVI movies. VLC media player offer you a feature in which you can add subtitles in any of your TV series and Movies.

You can Firstly Download Subtitles that support VLC media Player from these websites
https://moviesbar.in/websites-to-download-subtitles/

After that Play Video in which you want to add Subtitle by by using VLC media Player. Then Sinply go to Add Subtitle and Import Your Subtitle.